# How to get name of attributes annotated with fetch = FetchType lazy?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I want to get the list of attributes which have annotation with lazy fetch Type. I can do that through reflection and read it before hand. However I want to know if there is any other way to get list of lazy attributes before hand from `ClassMetaData` or `Persiter`? `getPropertyLaziness` is not returning correct result and so does getLazyProperties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getPropertyLaziness` method of `ClassMetadata` is supposed to return the correct values.

Did you try something like this :

```
ClassMetadata meta = sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(entity.getClass());
String[] propertyNames = meta.getPropertyNames();
boolean[] propertyLaziness = meta.getPropertyLaziness();

for (int i = 0; i < propertyNames.length; i++) {
    String propertyName = propertyNames[i];

    // Check if the property fetch type is Lazy
    if (propertyLaziness[i]) {
        System.out.println("Property : " + propertyName + " fetch type is Lazy");
    }
}
```

Comment: I did this only but I can't see propertyLaziness being true. I can see that in collectionMetaData they are lazy. However from CollectionMetaData I am not able to get OneToOne lazy as they are not collection